# Gradle does not download the dependencies of a package

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

I am using the latest version of android studio and I added some packages to the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.4.1@jar'
}
```

This packages are installed but there is a problem with retrofit. It does not download its dependencies like gson. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/1.4.1

I synchronized the project with gradle. Is this a problem with the gradle config or with retrofit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `@jar` suffix.

The `@foo` suffix forces resolution to a specific packaging and skips using the `pom.xml` which not only defines the packaging, but declares dependencies.